# Blog module for joomla

Tags: joomla

I am currently seeking a module Free blog for a Joomla site.

I just made the turn extensions on joomla.org but I found nothing!

I do not want to go through the standard features of joomla but by a module (management articles, pagination, comment section most commented, most read, RSS, short blog features).

You would not have used this type of module?

Answer (score -1):

Seems this needed some more searching from you. Joomla JED is full of Blog Extensions here [Joomla JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/authoring-a-content/blog)

Almost all of them can work as a blog as you described above.